# Nav/Subnav list, how to give clicked item active class after reload of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple nested & hidden sub-nav lists

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="profile" href="#">Profile</a>
    <ul id="profile">
        <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="structure.html">Structure</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a class="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
    <ul id="projects">
        <li><a href="chapter.html">Chapter</a></li>
        <li><a href="pblc-trde.html">Pblc Trde</a></li>
        <li><a href="globe.html">Globe</a></li>
        <li><a href="komforte.html">Komforte</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am currently using some jQuery i found online to show/hide the sub-nav upon click. What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. Hopefully clean up the show/hide click function of the sub-nab menus.
2. When clicking on the sub-nav menu items, the corresponding page that opens, needs to have the sub-nav expanded and give the corresponding menu item active class, so as to let the user know which page they are on.
3. I am hoping to do this purely in JS/jQuery. The installation of the site will be in WordPress.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   $(".profile").click(function () {
       var X = $(this).attr('id');
       if (X == 1) {
           $("#profile").hide();
           $(this).attr('id', '0');
       } else {
           $("#profile").show();
           $(this).attr('id', '1');
       }

   });

   //Mouse click on nav
   $("#profile").mouseup(function () {});


   //Document Click
   $(document).mouseup(function () {
       $("#profile").hide();
       $(".profile").attr('id', '');
   });


   $(".projects").click(function () {
       var X = $(this).attr('id');
       if (X == 1) {
           $("#projects").hide();
           $(this).attr('id', '0');
       } else {
           $("#projects").show();
           $(this).attr('id', '1');
       }

   });

   //Mouse click on nav
   $("#projects").mouseup(function () {});

   //Document Click
   $(document).mouseup(function () {
       $("#projects").hide();
       $(".projects").attr('id', '');
   });
   });

   window.onload = function () {
    $("ul#profile li:first").addClass("active");
   };

    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("ul#profile").show()
   });
   ```

Comment: You can use a combination of `document.location.href` (you'll need to do some manipulation of it) and `$('a[href=something]')` to find the link which points to the current page.

Comment: I added comments to the code in my answer, and made some tweaks to improve handling of more than one level of sub-menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Get the name of the page. Split the URL at the '/':s and get the last part
    // with pop():
    var pageName = (location.pathname).split('/').pop();

    // If we couldn't get a page name, default to index.html:
    if( pageName == '' )
    {
        pageName = 'index.html';
    }

    // Hide ul:s that are children of the navigation:
    $('.nav ul').hide();

    // Event handler for clicks on navigation links:
    $('.nav a').on('click', function()
    {
        // Change visibility for the first ul-child of the current li.
        // $(this) refers to the clicked element.
        $(this).parent('li').find('ul').first().toggle();

        // Hide other sub-menus:
        $(this).parents('li').siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
    });

    // Search through all link elements in the nav menu:
    $('.nav').find('a').each(function(index, value)
    {   
        // Append a '$' to the pagename to make the match()-function search
        // from the end of the href value:
        pageName += '$';

        if( value.href.match(pageName))
        {
            // If the pagename matches the href-attribute, then add the 'active'
            // class to the parent li, and show parent ul:s:
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').parents('ul').show();    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sir, you are amazing!! This works in exactly the fashion I was hoping for. I will take the time to review what you wrote and try to break it down and understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is only one small issue I see. When you have either of the sub nav menus open, and you click to open the other sub nav, it does not hide the previous sub nav

Comment: Edited to hide other sub-navs on click.

Comment: Perfect. Can't thank you enough, this has been bugging me for almost 2 weeks. I can move on finally. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cookie to hold the value of the currently open menu. This will allow for the value to be saved/retrieved between page loads and browser sessions.

As you've already got jQuery setup you can use the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to simplify things.

The code for it is quite simple (more examples on plugin page).

```
$.cookie('open_menu', 'projects'); //Save 'projects' under 'open_menu'
$.cookie('open_menu') //Returns 'projects'
```

Just check the value on page load and save it when one of the menu's is clicked.

If you'd prefer not to add any extra plugins here's some documentation on [JavaScript's inbuilt cookie API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie).

Edit: I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dracs/qMrBe/) with an example for you. The Cookie code doesn't seem to work in there sandbox, but the code should work for you, let me know if you have any troubles.

```
$(window).load(function() {
if ($.cookie('show_menu') !== undefined) {
    $('#' + $.cookie('show_menu')).click();
}

$('.nav > li > ul').each(function () {
    //Hide the sub lists
    $(this).hide();
    //Get link with same ID as Class
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //When link is clicked
    $('.' + id).click(function () {
        //Get the sub list
        var list = $('#' + $(this).attr('class'));
        //Check if it's currently visible
        if (list.is(':visible')) {
            list.hide(); //Hide list     
            $.cookie('show_menu', ''); //Unset open menu
        } else {
            $('.nav > li > ul').hide(); //Hide all other lists
            list.show(); //Show list
            $.cookie('show_menu', list.attr('class')); //Set open menu
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I am still pretty new to hand coding js so using this js Cookie is pretty difficult for me. I understand the concept of what needs to happen, but I dont know how to implement. I know this may be a difficult/lengthy question to answer, but frankly, I am completely stuck, any examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BrandonLeung I've added in an JSFiddle for you and some example code which should work for your HTML layout.