# How to activate links in a CSS-only hamburger menu?

Tags: css

Have this CSS-only hamburger menu set up in JSFiddle

> https://jsfiddle.net/jaygray/eu3r5qdk/2/

The hamburger is the upper-left rectangle above the breadcrumbs ('Home / Page 1')

The 'expander' is working as desired. My problem is that the link selector in the menu is not active and cannot trigger the URL.

**How to modify the JSFiddle example so that the link selector is active and opens the target URL?**

I have a working solution that uses `checkbox` and `label`. However, `Google AMP` does not allow those CSS properties, so I need a solution that fits the example above.

Here is  background and references from which I've learned:

1 AMP discussion:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/827

2 Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/d6qr7qsh/1/
http://jsbin.com/rokotubehi/1/edit?html,css,output
(Note: no selector or sub-menu)

3 Hamburger action:
http://codepen.io/chr1s1202/pen/sJBkD

4 Menu drawer:
http://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2014/04/23/pure-css-drawer-menu/

5 Off-screen navigation:
http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

6 Morphing menu button, partial selector:
http://www.scottohara.me/article/morph-button-updated.html

7 Drop-down menu that has a sub-dropdown menu in bootstrap:
[dropdown menu that has a sub-dropdown menu in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850836/dropdown-menu-that-has-a-sub-dropdown-menu-in-bootstrap)
@prem

8 How to create a responsive hamburger menu in AMP HTML:
[How to create a responsive hamburger menu in AMP HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136602/how-to-create-a-responsive-hamburger-menu-in-amp-html)
@John Pettitt

9 jQuery-type solution using nested and hidden sub-nav:
[Nav/Subnav list, how to give clicked item active class after reload of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488838/nav-subnav-list-how-to-give-clicked-item-active-class-after-reload-of-page)

10 Pure CSS Horizontal menu:
http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

So, to repeat:

**How to modify the JSFiddle example so that the link selector is active and opens the target URL?**

Comment: With over 1000 lines in total this is a huge [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wish there was an alternative. If I don't show what's working, the criticism would be 'show what you've done so far.' If I don't isolate the problem, it's more difficult to scope a solution to the problem. Once you face those competing criticism, the only remaining observation is: 'this problem is outside the scope of Stackoverflow.'